# You need to be root to execute - ansible

Tags: ansible

I have a lab setup with ansible controller + node and exploring few areas.

I am so far setup an user account named `ansible` in both machines and enabled ssh keybased authentication

Also setup sudo premissions for the user in both machines

When I try to run the below playbook , It works on the local machine and fails on the other node.

`--- #Install Telnet
- hosts: all
  name: Install Telnet
  become: true
  become_user: ansible
  become_method: sudo
  tasks:
   - yum:
      name: telnet
      state: latest`

Output is as follows 
`[ansible@host1 playbooks]$ ansible-playbook telnetDeployYUM.yml

PLAY [Install Telnet] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] **********************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [192.168.64.6]
ok: [192.168.64.5]

TASK [yum] **********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [192.168.64.5]
fatal: [192.168.64.6]: FAILED! => {"changed": true, "msg": "You need to be root to perform this command.\n", "obsoletes": {"grub2": {"dist": "x86_64", "repo": "@anaconda", "version": "1:2.02-0.64.el7.centos"}, "grub2-tools": {"dist": "x86_64", "repo": "@anaconda", "version": "1:2.02-0.64.el7.centos"}}, "rc": 1, "results": ["Loaded plugins: fastestmirror\n"]}
        to retry, use: --limit @/home/ansible/playbooks/telnetDeployYUM.retry

PLAY RECAP **********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
192.168.64.5               : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
192.168.64.6               : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1

[ansible@host1 playbooks]$
`

I could also manually able to run `sudo yum` on the failed target as ansible user

I believe sudo set up in correct

`[ansible@host2 root]$ sudo whoami
root`

Can experts share some insights on what I am missing with respect to my failed machine , Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below should work fine

```
- hosts: all
  name: Install Telnet
  become: yes
  tasks:
    - yum:
      name: telnet
      state: latest
```

ansible or user through which ansible is getting executed should be in sudoers file.

You are changing your user to ansible which is not required.

Answer (score 1):

Run with `-vvvv` to see what ansible is doing.

Have you setup `ansible` in `sudoers` for password less privilege elevation? 
you are getting a message that it is waiting for "escalation prompt". That means when you are running with become, you are failing to become since it needs the password. Make sure your test user is in `/etc/sudoers` AND you have it marked for that user to NOT need to enter a password when running sudo commands. The entry should end with `:NOPASSWD` on the line in that file.